# how to convert List of Integer to Array of Strings using Java 8 api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

given `List<Integer> count`, I want to produce `String[] countStr` using java 8.

```
example:
input

List<Integer> count = [1,2,3,4];

output

String[] countStr = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

I am familar with how to do this using `for-each` in java 7. I am wondering if I can get a concise way of doing this using java 8.

This is what I tried.

`String[] countStr = count.stream().map(String::valueOf).toArray();`

But I get compile error, that the above `toArray()` method returns `Object[]`.

Based on the comments, I tried the following:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);

        Stream<Integer> streamString = list.stream();
        String[] stringArray = streamString.toArray(size -> new String[size]);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer
    at java.util.stream.Nodes$FixedNodeBuilder.accept(Nodes.java:1222)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:576)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:255)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438)
    at TestDateParser.JavaApi(TestDateParser.java:40)
    at TestDateParser.main(TestDateParser.java:12)
```

Update:
This worked.

`count.stream().map(String::valueOf).toArray(size -> new String[size]);`

Comment: I dont understand how this is duplicate? the post mentioned does not answer what I am looking for. whoever marked duplicate does not even read through the question and simply marks duplicate in 30 secs. I am looking for List of Integers to Array of String.

Comment: It is duplicate: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690351/java-stringlist-toarray-gives-classcastexception 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030931/java-casting-list-of-strings-to-string-array

Comment: Yes this is a duplicate of the linked question which is more general: it explains how to convert a Stream to an array, which is the real problem here.

Comment: It is a duplicate. `count.stream().map(String::valueOf)` (your code) is a `Stream<String>`, so you want to convert a `Stream<String>` to a `String[]`. The marked duplicate tells you how to do that.

Comment: the marked duplicate DOES NOT answer, I tried what is suggested and I get ArrayStoreException. post updated

Comment: @Gremash: would you mind posting your solution in comment here.

Comment: @Tunaki: it is not stream conversion. It is object casting. my input is Integer and output should be string.

Comment: @brainstorm Do `count.stream().map(String::valueOf).toArray(size -> new String[size]);` This is just a combination of your original question and the answer in the duplicate.

Comment: There is no object casting here. Keep it plain / simple. Say again in English what you want to do, and then write. What do you want to do? You want to 1. Convert each integer into a String 2. Make an array out of that. Well 1. is answered by what you already have, i.e. `map(String::valueOf)` and 2. is answered by the dupe `.toArray(String[]::new)`.

Comment: Not a dupe, although the answers to both involve streams.